# create HDInsight Hadoop Cluster with Data Lake Store

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight, azure-data-lake

I am new user of azure,i want to connect a data lake with HDinsight,  I followed the instructions on azure documentation, but when i try to chose to connect a created data lake with HDinsight, i have this error Invalid emplacement.
Can you help me please ?

[Error hdinsight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1aQw.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Azure HDInsight cluster and the dependent storage(Blob or Data Lake Store) accounts must be in the same Azure location.

**For example:** If you have Azure HDInsight cluster in **East US** and Data Lake Store in **East US 2**, then you will receive **Invalid emplacement** error.

This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-hdinsight-hadoop-use-portal) explains how to use the Azure portal to create a HDInsight cluster with an Azure Data Lake Store account as the default storage or an additional storage.